# Export data to csv files using sqlcmd with special characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd, bcp

I am facing an issue while exporting data from a table to `CSV` file format using `SQLCMD` using SQL Query. The issue is with the data which contains special characters like degree Celsius (`°`) or `®`. The output is being converted to another value like `ø`. Please find the below query string which I am using.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -s, -W -Q "set nocount on; select * from ##XMLData_Output ORDER BY SKU_NUMBER" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "c:\Scripts\PED_Attributes.csv"'
```

The data in ##XMLData_Output is
[image]

After exporting the data, the output file looks like
[image]

Is there a way to get the output in the csv exactly like the input data? I have tried using multiple options like adding -f 65001 with no luck. I am using `SQLCMD` because I need to export the column names along with the data. If we can fix the issue in `SQLCMD`, it would be great. If we have another option to export the data from SQL Server to `csv` through some other way like `bcp` that would be also great. Please help me to fix this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered PowerShell's Invoke-SqlCmd | Export-Csv?

Comment: No. Is there a way to export the content with headers as well?

Comment: This was really helpful. I have tried using the powershell and it succeeded. Thank you. Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `-f` parameter to your call to sqlcmd to specify codepages for input and output.

Its syntax is

```
-f codepage | i:codepage[,o:codepage] | o:codepage[,i:codepage]
```

so for example:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -s, -W -f 1252 -Q "set nocount on; select * from ##XMLData_Output ORDER BY SKU_NUMBER" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "c:\Scripts\PED_Attributes.csv"'
```

or

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -s, -W -f o:65001 -Q "set nocount on; select * from ##XMLData_Output ORDER BY SKU_NUMBER" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "c:\Scripts\PED_Attributes.csv"'
```

(see sqlcmd doc at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15 and list of codepages at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers)

Comment: It did not help. I have used this format before as well. But result is the same.